# Getting Started with Heroku and OS X - can't login

Tags: macos, heroku, authentication

After I signed up and install Heroku toolbelt, I tried to login as instructions ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart ) say. I typed **$ heroku login** and I should get email and password prompt, but instead I get only one word in response: login. I don't know how to proceed and I tried to find solution - but I have no luck. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: can you copy and paste the terminal text you are seeing?

Comment: Sure ... Simons-MacBook-Pro:~ simon$ $heroku login  
login:

Comment: Did you try entering your email address and hitting enter?  I apologize if you have, but sometimes these things are not obvious...

Comment: Yes I tried. But response is : Login incorrect .

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did not misunderstand you ;-)

The binary `heroku` is either not installed, or not in your `$PATH`. When you type

```
$heroku login
```

with the leading `$`, the shell interprets `$heroku` as a variable, which is not set and it takes the next command `login`. This command lets you log in as another user on your machine…

So you have to find out what went wrong with the installation of Heroku, since you get `heroku: command not found`, as you wrote on my deleted answer.

If Heroku is installed correctly, you should be able to log in with this command (according to docs) in your Terminal.app:

```
heroku login
```

Comment: Wow, nice catch!  i hadn't considered that the OP may have been actually typing the command prompt $

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I finally find something. I used instructions from this article: http://samuelsharaf.wordpress.com/tag/heroku-install

To be more specific, I only used these commands:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
gem install heroku
```

Now it works fine. Thank you anyway for your time :)